# Cython build error: Buffer dtype mismatch

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, cython

Please I need a 64bit version of a non standard python module to work with my python(2.7) 64bit code but I have tried to compile the source code thus:

1. I compiled the `setup_Assignment.py` file to get an AoN.c file using SDK 7.0
2. I then compiled the `AoN.c` with a C compiler ie cl.exe.

But this error occured during the compilation of the C file:

```
fatal error c1083: cannot open include file:
    'pyconfig.h': No such file or directory
```

The above was done with 64bit compilers and a .pyd(dll) file was produced despite the error, which in turn generated this error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'ITYPE_t' but got 'long long'
```

When I tried to run the script with my 64bit python 2.7 (I use a windows 7 machine):

Below is the setup file that was compiled and the error I get. Please can I get help with figuring out what the errors point to. If the python script is needed I am willing to put it up, at this point I just think I have a lot up already.

Thank You!

*setup_Assignment.py:*

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

import numpy as np
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import subprocess
import Cython.Compiler.Options
Cython.Compiler.Options.annotate = True

setup(
      cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = [
              Extension("AoN",
                        ["AoN.pyx"],
                        include_dirs=[np.get_include()])
                    ]
     )
```

*Error gotten after running compiled file:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AMAMIFE/Desktop/obi/new.py", line 453, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/AMAMIFE/Desktop/obi/new.py", line 437, in main
    zones, loads=AoN.AllOrNothing(graph,demand,i)  #And assign
  File "AoN.pyx", line 58, in AoN.AllOrNothing (AoN.c:2138)
    _Ordering_and_Forward_Star(a_nodes,
  File "AoN.pyx", line 177, in AoN._Ordering_and_Forward_Star (AoN.c:3059)
    cdef _Ordering_and_Forward_Star(np.ndarray[ITYPE_t, ndim=1, mode='c'] a_nodes, #A_Node/B_Node
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'ITYPE_t' but got 'long long'
```

Comment: are you trying to wrap the C code?

Comment: @ Saullo Castro, the code is a cython code, that I need to use as an extension in python. Thanks

Comment: Can we see where `ITYPE_t` gets defined (presumably a `ctypedef` declaration somewhere in `AoN.pyx`)?

Comment: @ali_m it is quite a lengthy code, but I will put it up anyway

Comment: @ali_m optionally is there a way to share the code with you

Comment: @Nobi you can create a Gist in Github and share the link. If you can you should do it so that the people can help you out faster. The first error is probably because the C package is not in the `INCLUDE` environment variable of the compiler (you can also pass `-I/path_to_c_code/`), for the second error we must have more details

Comment: @Saullo Castro. Thanks for your help, this is the link to the gist I have created. https://gist.github.com/Nobik2/5c6197d4af4b5fe888a6

Comment: @Nobi I saw one mistake... cython float is the equivalent of numpy.float32. Do you have the full traceback of the error regarding `ITYPE_t`?

Comment: @SaulloCastro will put it up in a bit, but look at the one I have up here and see if its the one you expect. I have pasted it on the github gist page

Comment: @Nobi I think I found it... after `ind = np.lexsort((b_nodes,a_nodes))` add the line `ind = ind.astype(ITYPE)` and check if it helps...

Comment: @SaulloCastro please can you point me to the line number, thank you. Its 48 I got it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54087/discussion-between-saullo-castro-and-nobi).